# Unable to see shared folders in Samba

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, samba, file-sharing, shared-folders

I am trying to create a shared folder.

Installed Samba (as I have done on plenty of occasions for other releases) create the shared folder, all the appropriate privileges, etc, all with no problem.

However, I cannot see the shared folder on any other PC on my local network. The other PC's are Ubuntu 10.10 and a WinXP.

Is there a hidden file I have to alter? I have checked the Samba config and that seems all ok.

I do rely on a GUI, but I have a little terminal knowledge and checked what I can.

The strange thing is that the Ubuntu 11.10 PC can see a storage server running Ubuntu 10.04, but cannot see a shared folder on a PC running 10.10.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 64bit, is 32bit less buggy?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why but after some updates the issue has been resolved. The 64bit, has proven to be very stable and networking fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates resolved issues for me

Answer (score 0):

some thing to do with samba config utility i am trying to figure out but here is a clue http://www.noobslab.com/2011/07/samba-installation-on-ubuntu-11-041110.html

my problem is i can get samba config utility work